# Prove that if a matrix A is symmetric, then it is diagonalisable

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I need to prove that if a matrix $A_{2 \times 2}$ is symmetric, i.e., $A^t = A$, then it is diagonalisable.

I know that a matrix $M_{n \times n}$ is diagonalisable, if and only if there is a basis of $K^n$ consisting of its eigenvectors. That is, I must have $n$ linear independent eigenvectors of $M$.

So, in order to prove that the matrix $A$ is diagonalisable, I must prove that it has $n$ linear independent eigenvector.

Matrix A has the following form:
$$
A =
\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
 a & b \\
 b & c
\end{array} } \right]
$$

Therefore, its characteristic equation is:
$$
(\lambda -a)(\lambda -c) -b^2 =0
$$

Now I need to solve this equation in order to find its eigenvalues in terms of $a$, $b$ and $c$.

I'm not sure how to follow from here.

Comment: You can show directly that $0=(\lambda-a)(\lambda-c)-b^2=\lambda^2-(a+c)\lambda+(ac-b^2)$ have solutions. Calculate $\Delta=(a+c)^2-4(ac-b^2)$ and shows that $\Delta>0$.

Comment: @Yuki: Dear Yuki, Unless $A$ is a scalar matrix, in which case $\Delta = 0$; but this case is particularly easy!  Regards,

Comment: Indeed, I missed! Thanks Matt E!

Comment: @João Daniel: The result is true even for $n \times n$ symmetric matrices.

Comment: @Marvis, yes, but it's not quite as easy to prove.

Comment: @GerryMyerson True. I just wanted to make the OP aware of this :).

Comment: What sufficient conditions do you know for the diagonalizability of a matrix? Do you know that an $n\times n$ matrix with $n$ distinct eigenvalues is diagonalizable?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Yes, because $n$ distinct eigenvalues will give me $n$ LI eigenvectors, right?

Comment: Yes. So then proving that this matrix is either diagonal, or has two distinct eigenvalues, will establish the result you want.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As has been noted, the conclusion holds even for $n\times n$ matrices, $n\geq 2$. In fact, a symmetric $n\times n$ matrix with real coefficients is not just diagonalizable, it is *[orthogonally diagonalizable](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/22753/742):* you can find an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors.

But for your purposes it suffices to show that a $2\times 2$ symmetric matrix is either diagonal (when $b=0$), or else has two distinct eigenvalues.

If $b=0$, there is nothing to do, so assume $b\neq 0$. The characteristic polynomial is, as you note,
$$(t-a)(t-c)-b^2 = t^2 - (a+c)t + (ac-b^2).$$
The discriminant of this quadratic is
$$(a+c)^2 - 4(ac-b^2) = a^2+2ac+c^2 - 4ac + 4b^2 = a^2-2ac+c^2 +4b^2 = (a-c)^2+(2b)^2.$$
Since this is a sum of squares, it is nonnegative. Since $b\neq 0$, it is actually positive. Since the discriminant of the quadratic is positive, the polynomial has two distinct real roots, so the matrix has two distinct eigenvalues, hence is diagonalizable.

In conclusion, a symmetric $2\times 2$ matrix is either diagonal (and hence diagonalizable), or has two distinct eigenvalues (and hence is diagonalizable).

Comment: One might say, it's either diagonalized or diagonalizable.

Comment: What if the matrix has complex entries?

Comment: @UngarLinski A complex symmetric matrix need not be diagonalizable: $\left(\begin{array}{cc} 3&i\\ i&1\end{array}\right)$ is not diagonalizable: it has a repeated eigenvalue, and is not diagonal.